# is it possible to link a OLLVM compiler with Cython to produce a shared object file? (.pyd or .so)

Tags: python, llvm, cython, obfuscation

i am using

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

within that file is

```
ext_modules = [
    Extension('my_module', ['my_module.py'])
]

setup(
    name='Sample Program',
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
)
```

i want to link a OLLVM (https://github.com/obfuscator-llvm/obfuscator) for example this, to compile but also get a .dll or .so file, is that possible?